# Some results of my grad research have been used in a recent paper, but I was not told. Should I do something about it?

Tags: publications, authorship, research-undergraduate

*Some* of the work I did during my undergrad research (before my PhD, 4 years ago), exactly *two figures*, have been used in a recent paper. My ex-adviser (at the time of my undergrad research) is co-authoring the paper but she did not tell me about it. We kept being in contact after my undergrad research and we had planned to write a paper, then I started my PhD somewhere else and it did not succeed.

As I keep having good relationship with her, I don't know if I should do anything about it.

Comment: Indicate in the question whether a citation to your work was given.  That information can significantly affect the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should have been cited, at least, if the old figures were used and you created them. There may even have been a copyright violation here as figures are sometimes (often?) considered to be a "complete" work for such purposes.

You could ask for an explanation. You could express disappointment for the lack of acknowledgement. I can't predict the outcome, however. It might be an apology. It might be rage. What should happen is a correction, but that doesn't seem very likely.

I'm assuming, of course, that the figures really were re-used, rather than just being similar and generated from the same data.

But you have to judge whether to rock the boat a bit. It is your right to do so. If you need her as a source for your future advancement, then tread carefully.

Comment: Actually, one figure is the exact same, while the other was augmented to include more data in time. Co-authorship or IP rights are not a problem either, as I consider that my work is free to be used. My reaction is more related to the fact that we could have published a paper together, but instead of that some of my work was used in a different study, which I regret. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this depends on how substantial these figures and the work you put into them were. If these are standard figures that I'd have done myself anyway, or figures I had encouraged the student to do, I wouldn't feel bad about using them in my publication, at least after it's clear that there won't be a joint paper about this work. I'd probably still tell the student in advance that I plan to do this and mention the student in the Acknowledgements, however I don't think the student can claim an "intellectual right" on such things.

If it was your idea to do these figures and there's some of your own original thought and proper research work (on top of doing what you had been asked to do) in them, the situation is different. However in this case I agree with the answer by Buffy.